# WinDbg - can it be downloaded

Tags: windows-xp, minidumps, windbg

I have a machine that gives me a BSOD at least once a day.  I see a number of references here to WinDbg, where can I find that so I can look at the minidumps from the BSODs.
Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg is part of the Debugging Tools for Windows package.  Microsoft has published instructions on how to install the Debugging Tools for Windows [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx).

Basically you need to install the Windows SDK.  From the SDK installer you can choose to just install the debugging tools, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Microsoft WDK website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365) and scroll down far enough. There's a WinDbg download which does not let you download the whole SDK.

WinDbg is a very complex and if you never used it, you'll give up. Therefore I'd recommend  [Nirsoft Bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html), which gives you the necessary codes easier and faster.